# Node Server does not automatically restarts after deployment on Google App Engine

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, server, google-cloud-platform

I have a NodeJS Application that I deploy on Google App Engine Platform. Everything was working fine till last week. But now whenever I deploy the application on Gcloud app engine, the server does not get automatically restart. I always have to stop the instance and start it again to restart the server to serve the latest deployed code. I have 4 different servers and this is happening with each one of them. I don't think this is related to some code that I have in my application. I am using a paid plan of Google Cloud Platform.

Any help on this will be highly appreciated.